# Angular2 notify Component about DOM elements created outside angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular2-directives

## The Problem

I'm using Swiper carousel in my Angular2 project. Building it with Webpack.
As we all know Angular2 attaches to all elements in a component some random attributes like `_ngcontent-pmm-6`.

Swiper creates dynamically elements for pagination (dots, bullets, call them how you want). As I understand this happens outside of Angular. So this elements don't have those funky attributes, Angular don't know about them.

Now the problem: When Angular is processing the css of a component(added via `styleUrls`), it adds this attributes to css selector

`.swiper-pagination-bullet { ... }`

become

`.swiper-pagination-bullet[_ngcontent-pmm-6] { ... }`

But the pagination was rendered outside of Angular and new elements don't have this attribute, so the style **will not work**.

## The Question

How can I notify Angular2 about elements created outside of Angular?

#### Reference

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#inspect-generated-css

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround to solve the problem with styles. But this is not answering my question. If someone know, will be very graceful to hear!

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'cmp',
    template: `<div class="cmp">Component</div>`,
    styles: ['.cmp { border: green 2px solid; }'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // Use to disable CSS Encapsulation for this component
})

export class Component {
    constructor() { }
}
```

Answer was found here:
https://coryrylan.com/blog/css-encapsulation-with-angular-2-components

Comment: Alternatively you can add CSS directly to your `index.html`. Angular doesn't rewrite this CSS and it will therefore not be limited to matching `_ngcontent-...` classes.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I tried this too, but I thought there is a more gentle problem solving. You know, starting to separate CSS all the way through app, is not a good idea. That's the idea of a `Component` - keep all the code together that is related to it.

Comment: Sure, this works fine if you go the Angular2 way all along. The Angular2 way is to modify only the model and let Angular update the DOM accordingly. Updating the DOM directly doesn't fit in, therefore you need "hacks".